# You can gain reputation from edits to tag wikis, although they are not accessible through the API.

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, tags

Reputation gain from edits to tag wikis appear through the API; the API reports them as answers, but fetching them via the /answers route does not work.

Case in point:

- [My accepted edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/edit-suggestions/24) (+2 rep)
- My reputation report via the API:

  ```
  {
    "user_id": 23,
    "post_id": 15885,
    "post_type": "answer",
    "positive_rep": 2,
    "negative_rep": 0,
    "on_date": 1296727329
  },
  ```
- The reply for [/answers/15885](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/answers/15885):

  ```
  {
    "total": 0,
    "page": 1,
    "pagesize": 30,
    "answers": []
  }
  ```

(`/questions/15885` also gives no results.)

Comment: I tagged 1.0 because apparently [a new version of the API, 1.1, is going live "soon."](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/32493671597211648)

Comment: interesting tweet discovery! I wonder why Jeff seems to prefer leaking such [API relevant information](http://stackapps.com/q/1803/) elsewhere rather than announcing it here first (or at least as well) ...

Comment: @Steffen I think the problem is SOIS iterates too fast to keep us in the loop :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation gains from suggested edits are no longer returned by that route.

Comment: Ah, the joys of backwards compatibility :)